# How to NOT clear fields of one form when making submit request of another form on same route?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Main form (Employee Form), and another small form (Add Experience) that belong to the same route. The logic is when a specific information is missing from the main form, I will use the other form to update the database (i.e., the custom function), and continue working on the main form which has about 50+ fields.

When I submit the information for the second form to update the database, the fields from the main form are getting cleared. Having to fill up 50+ fields all over again is painful, hence I am looking for a way to work around this.

[Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3wmX.png)

APP.PY

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, FloatField, validators
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret'

class EmployeeInfo(FlaskForm):
    fullName = StringField('Full Name',[validators.InputRequired()])
    dept = StringField('Department',[validators.InputRequired()])

class CompanyDetails(FlaskForm):
    yearsOfExp = IntegerField('Year of Experiece',[validators.InputRequired()]) 

def custom_function(val):
    print(f"This employee has {val} years of experience.")

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'] )
def index():
    companydetails = CompanyDetails()
    employeeInfo = EmployeeInfo()

    if request.method == "POST" and employeeInfo.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('showData.html', form1=employeeInfo) 

    if request.method == "POST" and companydetails.validate_on_submit():
        val = request.form["yearsOfExp"]
        custom_function(val)

    return render_template('index.html',form1 = employeeInfo, form = companydetails)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True, port=5000)
```

TEMPLATES/INDEX.HTML

```
<html>
    <body>  
        <h4> Employee Form </h4>
        <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('index')}}" >
            {{ form1.csrf_token }}
            {{ form1.fullName.label }} {{ form1.fullName }}
            {{ form1.dept.label }} {{ form1.dept }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <hr>

        <h4>Add Experience</h4>
        <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('index')}}">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            {{ form.yearsOfExp.label }} {{ form.yearsOfExp }}       
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

TEMPLATES/SHOWDATA.HTML

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        {% if form1 %}
        <h2> Employee Details </h2>
            {{ form1.fullName.data }}
            {{ form1.dept.data }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if form %}
            <h2> Company Details </h2>
                {{ form.yearsOfExp.data }}      
        {% endif %}     
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought of an alternative using cookies, but it doesn't seem like the most correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about flask_wtf, maybe there is a better way within that package to do this. What I do is to put an event listener on the submit button and manually send the data to flask without reloading the page or clearing the form.

So an event listener could look like this:

```
(() => {
  'use strict'

  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over forms and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      
      form.submit()
      //form.reset()
      }

    }, false)
  })
})()
```

This is a modified example for [bootstraps client-side input validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/). For this to work, you add the `.needs-validation` class to all forms you wish to be validated `<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('index')}}" class=".was-validated">` (it's a bootstrap class, so you might need to create this yourself if you work without it.) and at the end of your index.html you load the script like this: `<script src="static/check.js"></script>`.

Now in the script, you check for all forms containing the desired class and create an array containing all of them. Now you create an event listener for every submit button within this forms-array. Whenever the submit-button is pressed, the `event.preventDefault()` stops the site from reloading, what would clear your fields. The `form.submit()` sends your form to the flask application as the submit button would do normally. (this is where maybe flask-wtf might be doing things differently, and I can't test this at the moment) The commented `form.reset()` would again reset your fields to default values, so you don't want that here.

If you would rather not do this for all forms, but only a few, you could also give them an id and select them with the `document.getElementById()`. [Mozilla has an interesting read about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)